# Display username in URL - Django

Tags: python, django, url, django-views, django-templates

When I try to display the username in the URL, I get this error:

Reverse for 'account_home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['/(?P\w+)/$'].

Here is my views.py

```
@login_required
def account_home(request, username):
    u = MyUser.objects.get(username=username)
    return render(request, "accounts/account_home.html", {})
```

Here is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('accounts.views',
    # url(r'^account/$', 'account_home', name='account_home'),
    url(r'^/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'account_home', name='account_home'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'auth_logout', name='logout'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'auth_login', name='login'),
    url(r'^register/$', 'auth_register', name='register'),
)
```

This is the code it is trying to render, but can't.[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer:** The problem is with your template code. You are not passing the `username` parameter to your view. Instead of

```
<a href="{% url 'account_home' %}">Account<a>
```

try

```
<a href="{% url 'account_home' user.username %}">Account<a>
```

**Long answer**: That being said, you could probably get rid of the `username` parameter by modifying your view instead. You already have the current user in the `request` object in your view:

```
@login_required
def account_home(request):
    u = MyUser.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    return render(request, "accounts/account_home.html", {})
```

and remove it from the url definition:

```
url(r'^$', 'account_home', name='account_home'),
```